# Зачем указывать для кнопки text-align: center?

Tags: css

Зачем указывать для кнопки `text-align: center;`, если визуально это ни на что не влияет? Это свойства указаны у большинства CSS Framework.

**Пример с [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp)**

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<button>Default Button</button>
<a href="#" class="button">Link Button</a>
<button class="button">Button</button>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Input Button">
```

Comment: А вы задайте ширину побольше для Link Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы установите ширину вручную, или же кнопка по какой-то причине примет ширину родителя, то текст с `text-align: center` в ней будет всегда по центру.

Для кнопки `<button>` и `input` с установленными `type` это действительно ни на что не влияет, потому что по умолчанию центрирование и так задано.

```css
.block{
  width: 100%;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>Button: </div>
  <button class="btn">Кнопка</button>

  <button class="btn center">Кнопка</button>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div>Input: </div>
  <input class="btn" value="Кнопка">
  
  <input class="btn center" value="Кнопка">
  
  Но при submit или button:
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="Кнопка">
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div>a: </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Кнопка</a>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn center">Кнопка</a>
</div>
```